# Confused on verb conjuation U-verbs ru-verbs or godan ones?

Tags: verbs, terminology

I am doing japaneese N5 lessons for second time and I get REALLY confused.
As far as I know there are 3 categories of verbs:

- Irregular verbs
- Ichidan verbs
- Godan verbs

But the sensei tells us that there are the following categories:

- Irregular ones
- U-verbs
- RU-verbs

And I got pretty much confused on this issue: which is the appropriate one classification, are U-verbs just godan ones or not?

Comment: They are the same things, just with different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology generally used to teach Japanese grammar to foreign language students is different from the terminology used to teach Japanese grammar to students in Japanese public school.

While the concept of "U-verbs", "RU-verbs", etc. are commonly taught to foreign language students, Japanese public school students only learn Godan, Ichidan, etc.

Broadly speaking:

- **U-verbs** are Godan Verbs（五段活用動詞{ごだんかつようどうし}）
- **RU-verbs** are Ichidan Verbs（下一段{しもいちだん}活用動詞、上一段{かみいちだん}活用動詞）
- **Irregular Verbs** are like "suru"（サ行変格{ぎょうへんかく}活用動詞）、"kuru"（カ行変格活用動詞）、etc.

Comment: "The terms are not exactly equivalent however, because the division between Godan and Ichidan is not exactly the same as the division between U-verbs and RU-verbs." Can you give an example of that? I can't think of one.

Comment: 困{こま}る is a RU-verb, but it is Godan

Comment: I was always taught that you can have u-verbs that end in る. Which is what would bridge that gap. Here's an example of a page from Tae Kim's guide, where 困る is listed as an u-verb. http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/define

Comment: Oh, you're right. I see what you mean. Yes, exceptions are also taught as to the general way to classify u-verbs and ru-verbs. I had forgotten about that.

Comment: This is why I personally prefer the term "consonant-stem verbs" to "u-verbs" or "type I verbs"...

Comment: However, there are named subdivisions of ru-verbs in the case of kami-ichidan and shimo-ichidan.

Comment: Yeah, using the u-veb / ru-verb terminology just kind of delays the inevitable revelation that sometimes you can't tell from the ending what it is.

Comment: To me ru-verb is really a misnomer, and as you say, just sets the learner up for confusion later on.

Comment: I think they're *meant* to be the same groupings, and as such you have to understand that RU-verbs does not mean "all verbs that end in -RU". Which is annoying in a different way, and still doesn't help the learner understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is a difference of behavior between the ます-form and the dictionary form. Compare two verbs with きる as dictionary form: 着る yields 着ます and 切る gives 切ります. In the former case what's conserved is *ki*-, with the latter what is common between the two forms is *kir*-. One stem ends on a vowel, the other on a consonant (to which five possible vowels can be added, hence *godan*).

I personally loathe the term 'type-1 verbs', since it is used for those verbs that are *not* 'ichidan' -- now that's not a clever choice of name.

Note that while there are only two official irregular verbs (来る and する), some other verbs have at least one irregular form (the negation of ある is ない, and 行く has 行て as a て-form).

Comment: > "行く has 行て as a て-form" - you mean 行って?